# All superscript (and subscript) font

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, typesetting

#### Background

I am creating an app with React Native which needs to be able to display super/subscript. For some reason, there is no way of doing this on Android because the `View` cannot be nested in the `Text` component. (More about my issue with React Native.)

#### Question

I am trying to find a font which consists solely of superscript characters and another font consisting solely of subscript characters. This font should include all letters of the alphabet, all numbers and all characters that are used often in maths. Because of this requirement, simply using Unicode for this will not work because it has no subscript character for the letter *b* for example.

If it doesn’t exist, would it be possible to make one? Or is that something you can’t do on font level? E.g., I am not sure if it is even possible to add padding to the bottom of each character as they are vectors. What would be another option?

Comment: I [moved all comments to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83479/discussion-on-question-by-bram-vanbilsen-all-superscript-and-subscript-font), since I consider most of them to either be addressed by edits or extended discussion around answers written as comments. Please: 1) Continue discussions in chat, if you want to. 2) Post information about how superscript and subscripts are handled nowadays as answers. 3) Use comments only for their intended purpose. 4) Edit all clarifying information into the question.

Comment: I would migrate this to stackoverflow because I'm 100% sure that you can add super/subscript to React Native apps. At the very least, you would create a `Superscript`/`Subscript` component which styles the children content as appropriate.

Comment: Relevant thread there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002583/superscript-text-in-react-native

Comment: @mrcharlie Not exactly, the solution they provide does not meet my requirements because it uses View components which limit my inline. I do not want to go in detail about it because this is not the appropriate forum, but the solution I need is only available on iOS in RN. I have had a thread open with a bounty on SO with 0 solutions. That is why I opened this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/) in your React Native App and they have a [subscript style](https://fontawesome.com/icons/subscript?style=solid&from=io) that can be automatically applied.

Comment: It isn't a subscript style, it simply are a few ( maybe 10) icons that have subscript (feel free to correct me if I am wrong btw), which isn't what I am looking for. I need to be able to make subscript text with all characters.